# How to fix Tomcat Serveral ports problem?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat, port

> Several ports (8005, 8080) required by Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost
> are already in use. The server may already be running in another
> process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this
> server you will need to stop the other process or change the port
> number(s).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsplG.png)

In this problem, how can I fix this? This error occurred when STS was newly installed separately from the existing Eclipse.

I tried to this solution.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vLkU.png)

Comment: Kill all java processes and try again?

Comment: Make sure you didn't start tomcat twice (e.g. by pressing the run button twice). Have you checked for port 8005 as well?

Comment: I checked port 8005 also but it didn't exist

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot, you could specify the port number of your server in the application.conf or application.yml file, for example if you are using an .yml extension:
[image]

or if you are using the .conf extension:

```
server.port=8081
```

the file could be found at: /src/main/resources/

Also you could list who is using your port by doing on CMD :

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>
```

and then kill the PID that uses your port:

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```